# SQLAlchemy: check if RelationshipProperty is scalar

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to programmatically build a query where I apply a filter to a relationship using `any()` or `has()`. My code does not know if the relationship is one-to-one or one-to-many, so to avoid this error:

```
InvalidRequestError: 'any()' not implemented for scalar attributes. Use has().
```

.. I currently have to write a test like this:

```
try:
    new_filter = relationship.any(filter)
except InvalidRequestError:
    new_filter = relationship.has(filter)
```

I would prefer use an if statement. Does RelationshipProperty have an attribute that indicates whether it is a scalar?

The documentation of [RelationshipProperty](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty) does not mention anything like `is_scalar` or any getter for `uselist`, and I cannot see any such attribute in here:

```
>>> dir(relationship)
['__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__clause_element__', '__delattr__', '__delete__', '__dict__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__radd__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__selectable__', '__set__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__weakref__', '_of_type', '_parententity', '_query_clause_element', '_supports_population', 'adapt_to_entity', 'adapter', 'any', 'any_op', 'asc', 'between', 'class_', 'collate', 'comparator', 'concat', 'contains', 'desc', 'dispatch', 'distinct', 'endswith', 'expression', 'extension_type', 'get_history', 'has', 'has_op', 'hasparent', 'ilike', 'impl', 'in_', 'info', 'is_', 'is_aliased_class', 'is_attribute', 'is_clause_element', 'is_instance', 'is_mapper', 'is_property', 'is_selectable', 'isnot', 'key', 'label', 'like', 'match', 'notilike', 'notin_', 'notlike', 'nullsfirst', 'nullslast', 'of_type', 'of_type_op', 'op', 'operate', 'parent', 'property', 'reverse_operate', 'startswith', 'timetuple']
```

The question relates to SQLAlchemy 0.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the values of the relationship attributes, there is one attribute `impl` that is of type `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.ScalarObjectAttributeImpl` if the relationship is scalar. So I have gone with the following test for now:

```python
is_scalar = isinstance(relationship.impl, ScalarObjectAttributeImpl)
```

Comment: 6 years later, in today's version 1.3.19, this still works. 